# How to store all selected values from 2 select boxes into an array with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select boxies like this:

```
<div class="info">
    <select name="type" class="data" onchange="getData(this.value);">
        <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
        <option value="student">Student</option>
    </select>
    <select name="class" class="data" onchange="getData(this.value);">
        <option value="1A">Class 1A</option>
        <option value="1B">Class 1B</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script>
    function getData() {
        var datas = [];
        $.each($('.data'), function (index, value) {
            if ($(value).prop('selected') == true) {
                datas.push($(value).val());
            }
        });
        console.log(datas);
    }
</script>
```

I want to store all selected  values in a array when onchange event called. But my code not working, any help ?

Comment: For both drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this using jQuery you can remove the outdated `onchange` attributes and use unobtrusive JS code to hook your events.

From there you can use `map()` to build an array from the selected values of all your `.data` elements. Try this:

```js
$('.data').change(function() {
  var selectedValues = $('.data').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

  console.log(selectedValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
  <select name="type" class="data">
    <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
    <option value="student">Student</option>
  </select>
  <select name="class" class="data">
    <option value="1A">Class 1A</option>
    <option value="1B">Class 1B</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `each` on `.data` to get all selected value from drop down. Check below code.

```js
$(".data").on("change", function () {
  var datas = [];
    $(".data").each(function () {
        datas.push($(this).val());
    })
    console.log(datas);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
    <select name="type" class="data" >
        <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
        <option value="student">Student</option>
    </select>
    <select name="class" class="data">
        <option value="1A">Class 1A</option>
        <option value="1B">Class 1B</option>
    </select>
</div>
```